# Media Notification reappears after closing app

Tags: android, flutter

Media Notification reappears after the app is closed and the audioPlayer is Stoped/Released. I am using the following library: [flutter native-audio](https://github.com/gaucidaniel/native-audio/tree/master/android/src/main/kotlin/com/danielgauci/native_audio)

This is for my flutter app, the dev for the library has the notification setup to stay alive when the app is closed. I want it to replicate the nature of Youtube Music, Apple Music on Android, Spotify, etc. These apps close the media notification and the media session.

I have the repo cloned and am editing the code but I can't figure out what I need to change in order to kill the media notification, audio player, media session, etc.

note: Flutter doesn't have a onDestory, otherwise it would be best for me to call stop/release using the library through onDestory. If it is known how to do this, that would be better than modifying the library

Answer (score 0):

NativeAudioPlugin.kt

```
var serviceConnection_GLOBAL: ServiceConnection? = null
var context_GLOBAL: Context? = null

context_GLOBAL = context
serviceConnection_GLOBAL = serviceConnection
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import com.danielgauci.native_audio.AudioService
import com.danielgauci.native_audio.context_GLOBAL
import com.danielgauci.native_audio.serviceConnection_GLOBAL

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    serviceConnection_GLOBAL?.let { context_GLOBAL?.unbindService(it) }
    context_GLOBAL?.stopService(Intent(context_GLOBAL, AudioService::class.java))

    finishAndRemoveTask()
    exitProcess(0)
  }
```